# How to import tab delimited data into Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007

Given tab delimited data that I am importing from Excel, how do I insert it into the spreadsheet so that it ends up in multiple cells like it does when I paste it.

**Edit:** I have the text in a variable, so I don't want to go through the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically what I finally came up with, it was a little more complex and used arrays, but that is the gist of it.

```
i = 1
For Each Row In VBA.Split(text, vbCrLf)
    j = 1
    For Each Col In VBA.Split(Row, vbTab)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Col
        j = j + 1
    Next Col
    i = i + 1
Next Row
```

Answer (score 3):

It should not be too hard. Please try: http://www.zerrtech.com/content/excel-vba-open-csv-file-and-import

If you want to do it from string variable, split text by end line:

```
Dim linesSplit As Variant 
linesSplit = Split(yourTextVar, "\n")
```

For each linesSplit, split by comma:

```
Dim lineSplit As Variant 
lineSplit = Split(linesSplit[i], ",")
```

Put result in worksheet. GL!

Comment: Is there a way besides through the file system?