# Excel VBA: Copy the Data up to the last column that has value

Tags: vba, excel

The spreadsheet has multiple values in a cell.

What I'm trying to do is get that value found in a cell and paste it to another sheet and copy the other fields(columns) that belong to that value. How do I set the range in order copy the other fields(columns) up to the last column that has value? Thanks in advance.

```
For iRowGetProdCode = 0 To UBound(sSplitProdCode)

    Sheets("Output").Cells(iRowCountOutput, 1).Value = sSplitProdCode(iRowGetProdCode)

    iRowCountOutput = iRowCountOutput + 1

Next iRowGetProdCode
```

Comment: Provide more information about what your data looks like, what you expect your code to do, and what it actually does. This question is not clear.

Comment: I think you're asking about **Resize** - for 1 row to containg all values in sSplitProdCode: `Sheets("Output").Cells(currentRow, 1).Resize(1, UBound(sSplitProdCode))` ?

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea how to discover an un-empty columns in the same row,

maybe you will find it useful and manipulate it for your needs:

```
Function LoopUntilLastColumn(ByVal Row As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While Cells(Row, i) <> ""
    ' do somthing
        MsgBox (" I AM ALIVE COLUMN!")
i = i + 1
Loop

    ' you can also use the return value of the function.
    LoopUntilLastColumn = i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about what you're asking, but here are my three best guesses.

**1.) Splitting delimited data from a single cell to columns**

- Without VBA: Use the "Text to Columns" function (Excel Ribbon:
  Data|Data Tools).
- With VBA: Use the split function [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) ([Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231420/how-to-import-tab-delimited-data-into-excel-using-vba)), then assign array values to target cells.  Or parse your string [manually with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778819/excel-2010-vba-step-through-a-string-and-place-one-char-into-each-cell-in-sequen).

**2.) Finding the end of a continuous range**

- Without VBA: Use ctrl + arrow key
- With VBA: Use the [Range.End Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx)

**3.) Looping through columns and rows**

- Used a nested loop:

  `For c = 1 to 5
      For r = 1 to 20
        Cells(r,c) = "Row = " & r & ", Column = " & C
     Next
  Next`

---

**Editing Suggestions** (I don't have enough reputation to directly comment or edit)

This question as worded may be too specific for StackOverflow.  Consider re-wording so that the problem can be understood in a general context and your question can be more useful to others.

Also, the wording is a little confusing.  For example, use of the term "value" seems to change from referring to delimited data to referring to cell content in VBA.  Likewise, it can be confusing to use "fields" or "columns" to describe the data if it's actually delimited text, so clarity on the data's state of existence would help.

It also seems to me that you've parsed the string on it's delimiter to an array, and that you're looping through this array to write the data in rows.  I still can't see how exactly your question about setting a range fits in.